# Foreign object detection code is working but along with foreign objects it detects missing object also. How to detect foreign object only

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, background-subtraction

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fUH892Q6hbfDnoXF1G3-ZPe_rFPCamPn/view?usp=sharing]

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/17ZiHIFTwMApmttT1HzDMasVGDgNlUJhM/view?usp=sharing]Actually I am working on foreign object detection using open cv python. I am capturing the first frame and subtracting all the rest of the frames so whenever there is a change from the first frame it will detect it as foreign object. After subtracting the frames from the first frame I am finding the contours and finding out the contours whenever a particular contour is remaining in the frame for particular number of frames(set by consecutive frames = 5) it will detect as foreign object. So something missing from the frame also is making a change in the foreground that's why it is detecting that also. I need a kind of solution, by that it will detect something added to the frames only. Please help me!!!

Actually I am working on foreign object detection using open cv python. I am capturing the first frame and subtracting all the rest of the frames so whenever there is a change from the first frame it will detect it as foreign object.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
import imutils

#file_path ='0'
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
grabbed, frame = cap.read()
#frame = imutils.resize(frame,width =500)
img = cv2.imwrite("shot.jpg",frame)
firstframe_path ='shot.jpg'

firstframe = cv2.imread(firstframe_path)

firstframe_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(firstframe,(21,21),0)
firstframe_gray = cv2.cvtColor(firstframe_blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


cv2.namedWindow('CannyEdgeDet',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('Abandoned Object Detection',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.namedWindow('Morph_CLOSE',cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

consecutiveframe=5

track_temp=[]
track_master=[]
track_temp2=[]

top_contour_dict = defaultdict(int)
obj_detected_dict = defaultdict(int)

frameno = 0
# roi = cv2.selectROI(frame,showCrosshair=False)
# cv2.destroyWindow('ROI selector')
# firstframe = firstframe[roi[1]:roi[1]+roi[3],roi[0]:roi[0]+roi[2]]
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    #frame = imutils.resize(frame,width =500)
    #roi = cv2.selectROI(frame,showCrosshair=False)
    #forig = frame.copy()
    #frame=frame[roi[1]:roi[1]+roi[3],roi[0]:roi[0]+roi[2]]



    if ret==0:
        break

    frameno = frameno + 1
    #cv2.putText(frame,'%s%.f'%('Frameno:',frameno),(50,50),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,255,255),2) 





    frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(firstframe, frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame_diff',frame_diff)
    frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame_diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    frame_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame_gray,(21,21),0)


    edged = cv2.Canny(frame_blur,10,200)
    cv2.imshow('CannyEdgeDet',edged)
    kernel2 = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
    thresh2 = cv2.morphologyEx(edged,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, 
    kernel2,iterations=2)
    #cv2.imshow('Morph_Close', thresh2)


    cnts,_ = cv2.findContours(thresh2.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE) 


    mycnts =[]
    for c in cnts:

        M = cv2.moments(c)
        if M['m00'] == 0: 
            pass
        else:
            cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
            cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])


            if cv2.contourArea(c) < 300: ##or cv2.contourArea(c)>20000:
                pass
            else:
                mycnts.append(c)

                (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
                sumcxcy=cx+cy
                #print(sumcxcy)



                #track_list.append(cx+cy)
                track_temp.append([cx+cy,frameno])


                track_master.append([cx+cy,frameno])
                #print("did:",did,frameno)
                countuniqueframe = set(j for i, j in track_master) # get a #set of unique frameno. then len(countuniqueframe) 

                #print("pip:",countuniqueframe)

                #------------------------------------------------------- 
                 ---------
                # Store history of frames ; no. of frames stored set by 
                #'consecutiveframe' ;
                 # if no. of no. of unique frames > consecutiveframes, 
                 #then 'pop or remove' the earliest frame ; defined by
                 # minframeno. Objective is to count the same values 
                 #occurs in all the frames under this list. if yes, 
                 # it is likely that it is a stationary object and not a 
                 #passing object (walking) 
                 # And the value is stored separately in 
                 #top_contour_dict , and counted each time. This dict is 
                 #the master
                 # dict to store the list of suspecious object. Ideally, 
                 #it should be a short list. if there is a long list
                 # there will be many false detection. To keep the list 
                 #short, increase the 'consecutiveframe'.
                 # Keep the number of frames to , remove the 
                 #minframeno.; but hard to remove, rather form a new list 
                 #without
                 #the minframeno.
                 #------------------------------------------------------ 
                 ----------
                if len(countuniqueframe)>consecutiveframe or False: 
                    minframeno=min(j for i, j in track_master)
                    for i, j in track_master:
                        if j != minframeno: # get a new list. omit the  those with the minframeno

                            track_temp2.append([i,j])

                    track_master=list(track_temp2) # transfer to the 
                    master list
                    track_temp2=[]


                #print 'After',track_master

                #count each of the sumcxcy
                #if the same sumcxcy occurs in all the frames, store in  master contour dictionary, add 1


                countcxcy = Counter(i for i, j in track_master)
                #print countcxcy
                #example countcxcy : Counter({544: 1, 537: 1, 530: 1, 
                #523: 1, 516: 1})
                #if j which is the count occurs in all the frame, store 
                #the sumcxcy in dictionary, add 1
                for i,j in countcxcy.items(): 
                    if j>=consecutiveframe:
                        top_contour_dict[i] += 1


                if sumcxcy in top_contour_dict:
                    if top_contour_dict[sumcxcy]>50:
                        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h),(255, 0, 0), 3) 

                        cv2.putText(frame,'%s'%('foreign_Object'),(cx,cy),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6,(255,255,255),2) 


                    #cv2.putText(frame, "foreign object !!!", (10,20),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.8, (0, 0, 255), 2) 

                    print ('Detected : ', sumcxcy,frameno,obj_detected_dict) 


                    # Store those objects that are detected, and store 
                    #the last frame that it happened.
                    # Need to find a way to clean the top_contour_dict, 
                    #else contour will be detected after the 
                    # object is removed because the value is still in 
                    #the dict.
                    # Method is to record the last frame that the object 
                    #is detected with the Current Frame (frameno)
                    # if Current Frame - Last Frame detected > some big 
                    #number say 100 x 3, then it means that 
                    # object may have been removed because it has not 
                    #been detected for 100x3 frames.

                        obj_detected_dict[sumcxcy]=frameno

    for i, j in obj_detected_dict.items():
        if frameno - obj_detected_dict[i]>200:
            print ('PopBefore',i,obj_detected_dict[i],frameno,obj_detected_dict)

            print ('PopBefore : top_contour:',top_contour_dict)obj_detected_dict.pop(i) 


            # Set the count for eg 448 to zero. because it has not be 
            #'activated' for 200 frames. Likely, to have been removed.
            top_contour_dict[i]=0
            print('PopAfter',i,obj_detected_dict[i],frameno,obj_detected_dict)  

            print ('PopAfter : top_contour :',top_contour_dict)



    #cv2.rectangle(forig, (roi[0], roi[1]),(roi[0]+roi[2],roi[1]+roi[3]), (0, 255, 0),1) 

cv2.imshow('Detections',frame)



    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I need a kind of solution, by that it will detect something added to the frames only.

Comment: Adding examples will really help in understanding the problem in detail. Additionally, there are several lines with "#" missing, please edit

Comment: Did that. Thanks

Comment: You still haven't added any examples

Comment: I don't have that much reputation to upload images so because of that I have uploaded  my issues with two screenshots and I have shared the drive link. You can now see that in the question now. In the first link you can see two notes of orange color and pink color that are in the first frame. So these are not foreign objects. In the second link I have added a foreign object which is the green note and at the same time I removed the orange note so you can see in the second picture it is detecting the added object and removed object(orange note) as foreign object.

Comment: I know that it is because, My algorithm which is based on whatever the changes from the first frame it will detect and if it remains for particular consecutive frames it should detect. So can you help me with few changes in the code that I have to make for making it to detect only added objects.